# When saving a file with Visual Studio Code editor the file owner is "Administrators"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Appologies if the subject is confusing...

When saving new or editing existing code on my PC with the Visual Studio Code editor, the ownership is being set as "Administrators". Due to access restrictions imposed by my company, I cannot change the ownership or other security settings under the security tab for the file. The issue persists (ineblility to change ownership) even after those with "the power" changed the permissions of the folders where I save my code.

If I open the same file (and save as) or create a new file in the same directory using notepad or even notepad++ then save, the file has me as the owner. This is an issue as the Git app upload fails when it "sees" I am not the file owner. Yes, I can copy / drag and drop to the Git repository but to me the Git app seems less confusing.

I attempted the steps provided for the Git error (something akin to a whitelist) but it did not work. So my question is this... how to get VS Code editor to save files with the expected file owner and not "Administrators". I am not anxious to go back and perform a "Save as..." for the files each time I wish to upload to Git. "Run as Administrator" option is NOT enabled for VS Code under the compatibility settings (right-click properties).

Comment: Maybe you can install visual studio as your own user? and run from your user space.

Comment: I think Pawel Dubiel is correct. Likely it should be saving files as either 1. `The user running it`, or else 2. `The user it's installed as`, or else 3. `the directory you're saving to is changing permissions of the files inside it`. One of those three things must be causing your problem. You've already checked #3 (Notepad++ is saving files correctly), so try installing your own copy of VScode for your local user. (If THAT doesn't solve your problem, try installing your own copy of GIT.)